# synchronize files between remote sftp location and local

Tags: storage, sftp, files, synchronization, local

I am facing a quite familiar problem but have no clear idea on how to handle it.

I'm a backend developer and i write my applications using Zend Studio. My employer requires me to work on a remote location using SFTP and expandrive. Although this works quite well on mac, it does however work less efficient on Windows. Sometimes it takes 30 seconds for me to access a file, and it sometimes hangs while i'm working on it. In the end this caused me to demolish 7 keyboards, 2 mice and a 23inch monitor :(.

What i would like to know is:

Is it possible for me to somehow create a sync between my local storage and a remote sftp location? That way i can work locally and the files that edit will be synced as soon as i hit the save button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinSCP has a 'Keep Remote Directory up to date' [feature](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date). Never used it, but WinCP being as stable as it is I'd at least try.

Comment: This is a good option, although it isnt working as well as i hoped it's probably my only option :(.

Answer (score 1):

If you were on Linux you might benefit from sshfs; as it is, I'd say you might benefit from a new employer (this one clearly has no consideration for the needs of their staff).  Stack Overflow Careers is just over `--->` [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)...